# get an array of objects via two has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :job
   has_many :items

 end
```

I want to get a list of items for a given @job. This solution works:

```
 @items = []

 @job.bookings.each do |booking|
     booking.items.each do |item|
         @items << item
     end
 end
```

But how can i do this more concisely? i.e. something like:

```
 @job.bookings.map{ |booking| booking.items }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Job` class put: `has_many :items, through: :bookings` and then you can call `@job.items` directly.